# Riemann Integral of $f(x)=1$ if $x=\frac{1}{n}$ where $ n\in N$ or $0$ otherwise

Tags: calculus, integration

Simple question. I have the function:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;\;x=\frac{1}{n}\;,\;\; n\in\mathbb{N}\\{}\\0 &,\;\;\; \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I am being asked whether it is Riemann integrable in $[0,1]$. My idea: for every finite partition of $[0,1]$ at least one interval $\Delta x_i$ contains infinite number of points where $f$ is $0$ and infinite number of points where $f$ is $1$. Therefor for different selection of points inside that interval, we will get a different Riemann sum.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yup, it is...nice!

Comment: $@$The-Q: I can't tell from your idea whether you are trying to show that the function is Riemann integrable or not Riemann integrable.  Which is it?

Comment: I am trying to find out whether it is or not, and prove it.

Comment: @The-Q I think this is Riemann integrable. You can look at my soln. and fell free to point out mistakes if there are any.

Comment: I understand that's the problem you're trying to solve.  But to have an idea to solve it, don't you need a guess as to whether it's true?  In the case at hand: in general when you select different sample points in a partition you get different Riemann sums.  The question is whether the difference between Riemann sums can be made to go to zero by limiting the maximum size of the subinterval in the partition.  What does your idea tell you about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there are many different versions of the definition of Riemann integrability, ultimately equivalent to each other, but not obviously so.  Which are you using?

For many purposes the easiest to use is **Darboux's Criterion**: it suffices to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $[a,b]$ such that

$U(f,\mathcal{P}) - L(f,\mathcal{P}) < \epsilon$.

(Here $U(f,\mathcal{P})$ and $L(f,\mathcal{P})$ are the upper and lower sums for the partition $\mathcal{P}$.)

Now a **hint**: fix an $\epsilon$ and choose a partition so that the subinterval containing each point $\frac{1}{n}$ is small, measured in terms of $\epsilon$.

Comment: For every $0<\epsilon<1$ (>1 is trivial), let n be such: $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon\leq\frac{1}{n-1}$. Partition will be $0<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{n-1}<\dots<1$. Maximum value in all but the first interval will be 0. Maximum value in first interval will be 1, so $U(f,\mathcal{P})=\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$   (while $L(f,\mathcal{P})=0$ in all intervals. Thank you!

Comment: I think the proof above has a hole in it, although it can be fixed really easily. Please correct me if I am wrong.

So where I think the flaw might be is that when we choose the intervals, we consider the closed intervals containing the endpoints and not the open ones. But considering the closed intervals of your partition, the supremum of each interval turns out to be $1$ which is attained at the endpoints.

Brilliant choice of the intervals BTW! Thanks to your idea, I think I can finish the proof.

Comment: The fix can be done by using a theorem that states that the integrability of a function _does not_ change if we change the values for _finitely_ many points. So after fixing $n$, we can basically use the following theorem to redefine $f(\tfrac 1n)=f(\tfrac 1{n-1})=\cdots=0$ and we are through! We can finish exactly in the way you did.

P.S.: (+1) There is no building without any foundation, so the idea of yours of creating the partition was just brilliant (which is sadly failed to do so :( ).

Answer (score 1):

I think the function is riemann integrable.

Let $\int_{U[a,b]}f,\int_{L[a,b]}f$ represent the upper riemann integral and lower riemann integral.

Let $0<\epsilon(<1)$ be given,

Consider the interval $[\epsilon,1]$. Then f is integrable in this interval because it contains finitely many points in this interval in which the functional value is $>0$.

In the interval $[0,\epsilon]$ we have $\int_{U[0,\epsilon]}f\le1.\epsilon=\epsilon$(because $f(x)\le1,\forall x\in[0,\epsilon])$ , and $\int_{L[0,\epsilon]}f>0$(as $f(x)\ge0 $ in this interval)

So we have $\int_{U[0,\epsilon]}f-\int_{L[0,\epsilon]}f\le \epsilon\Rightarrow $ $f|_{[0,\epsilon]}$ is integrable as $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary.

So $f|_{[0,\epsilon]},f|_{[\epsilon,1]}$ are both integrable implying $f$ is integrable.

Comment: I like the idea but not the execution: you can't say "as $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary" because as you shrink $\epsilon$ you are also shrinking the interval.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I cant understand what do you mean by "as you shrink ϵ you are also shrinking the interval"

Comment: To apply Darboux's Criterion (see my answer) you need a fixed interval, not an interval whose length goes to zero with $\epsilon$.  It is possible to fix this by getting estimates on the upper and lower sums on the entire interval.